# Custom android layout for Textfield element size

Tags: android, android-layout, size, textfield

Under my relative layout, I put in a `Textview` and then a `TextField` (both of them are aligned on the left hand side).

However, the `TextField` *can not* stretch to the width I want (well, it would stretch all the way if it touches the right hand side but not anywhere else).

How can I achieve that the Textfield stretches to any arbitrary length?

`Textfield` is the same as `EditText`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1">
 <TextView android:id="@+id/textItem"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:paddingTop="10dp"
  android:background="#00000000"
  android:textColor="#ffffffff"
  android:textSize="22sp" 
  android:text="Settings"
  android:enabled="false"  
   >
 </TextView>
 <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_weight="1.03">
     <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_marginTop="18dp"></TextView>
     <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1" android:layout_marginTop="18dp">
         <requestFocus></requestFocus>
     </EditText>
 </RelativeLayout>  
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not just being difficult here but do you mean that in your question you meant to say `EditText` or are you using some 3rd-party library which has a class called `TextField`? Either way, posting your XML layout file is the only way that people are going to be able to help.

Comment: Post your XML layout/code to save confusion and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android:layout_width="50dp". set the value to whatever size you want it to be.